# nullptr as flag value for boost::any map

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-any

If I set up a generic container map using `boost::any`, and use the new `nullptr` from C++11 as an initialization value akin to an `isset()` type operation, are there any potential pitfalls?

For example:

```
std::map<std::string, boost::any> map;
map["A"] = nullptr;
map["B"] = nullptr;
map["C"] = nullptr;
map["D"] = nullptr;

map["A"] = 1;
map["C"] = 3;

// assume error checking, other types, etc.
for(auto k : map) {
    if (k.second.type() != typeid(nullptr)) {
        std::cout << k.first << " : " << boost::any_cast<int>(k.second) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Before C++11, I had the `boost::any` wrapped in a struct with a `bool isset`, but this seems to be working. Any pitfalls?

Comment: From the code you post here it looks like you want `boost::optional`, not `boost::any`.

Comment: That's interesting, and I had not seen it before. I would still have to use `boost::any` as the type of `boost::optional`, because I need the second value in the map to be generic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't see any pitfalls as such (beyond being careful to specifically set it to `nullptr_t` and not any other pointer type); but why not just leave it empty, and check it with its `empty()` member function?

Comment: Ack. I could, uh, give an elaborate reasoning why I wouldn't use the `empty()` member, but the truth is I've ... somehow missed that function until now. Egg on my face.